# Using integer counters in batch file (Restore MySQL Database)

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I'm creating a `bat` file to automatically restore a MySQL database from a `sql` file. Here is the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM author: Gideon Apollo Bardelas
SET attempt=0
SET MAX_ATTEMPT=4

@ECHO Deploying database on MySQL Server.
IF "%MYSQL_HOME%" == "" GOTO NOHOME

:YESHOME
SET mysql=%MYSQL_HOME%
@echo Running MySQL on the MYSQL_HOME...
GOTO :RUN_SCRIPT

:NOHOME
@ECHO.
@ECHO MySQL Server is not detected on the system.

:NOHOME_CONFIRM
set /p cho=Do you have a MySQL server installed (y/n)? %=%
if %cho%==Y goto :NOHOME_ASK
if %cho%==y goto :NOHOME_ASK
if %cho%==n goto :NOHOME_QUIT
if %cho%==N goto :NOHOME_QUIT

@echo Invalid choice.
goto :NOHOME_CONFIRM

    :NOHOME_ASK
    @ECHO.
    set /p temp_path=Please give your mysql directory (Q to terminate): %=%

        :NOHOME_PATH_VERIFY
        if %temp_path%==Q goto :END
        if %temp_path%==q goto :END
        IF EXIST %temp_path%\mysql.exe GOTO :NOHOME_PATH_ACCEPT
        GOTO :NOHOME_PATH_REJECT

        :NOHOME_PATH_ACCEPT
        SET mysql=%temp_path%
        @echo Running MySQL on the specified directory...
        GOTO :RUN_SCRIPT

        :NOHOME_PATH_REJECT
        @echo Cannot find mysql.exe in the specified directory.
        GOTO :NOHOME_ASK

    :NOHOME_QUIT
    @echo.
    @echo Please install first MySQL Server on your system to continue.
    GOTO :END

:RUN_SCRIPT
SET attempt=attempt+1
set /p username=MySQL username:  %=%
set /p password=MySQL password:  %=%
%mysql%\mysql -u %username% -p%password% mysql < schema.sql 1>NUL 2>NUL || GOTO :VALIDATE
GOTO :SUCCESS

    :VALIDATE
    if %attempt% EQU %MAX_ATTEMPT% (
        @ECHO.
        @ECHO You have reached maximum attempts to log in MySQL Server.
        GOTO :END
    ) ELSE GOTO :RUN_SCRIPT

    :SUCCESS
    @ECHO.
    @ECHO Finished deploying server.

:END
set /p cho=Press any key to quit. %=%
```

This already worked, until I've decided to add a validation that when the user has already attempted three times to log on MySQL, it will terminate the batch file. The problem is that **the counter doesn't work**. It will continue to ask for a MySQL credential until it receives a proper one.

I think that the problem originates on the `:VALIDATE` clause. But I cannot fixed it.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
SET attempt=attempt+1
```

to do arithmetics with `set`, you have to use the `/a`parameter:

```
set /a attempt=%attempt%+1
```

You can use variables without `%` with `set /a`:

```
set /a attempt=attempt+1
```

or use a shorter form:

```
set /a attempt+=1
```